# Installing Openbravo on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat6, apt-get, openbravo

Since I'm asked by my boss to integrate an Openbravo platform and develop several modules on it, I need a reliable development environment, and I'm currently only running Ubuntu 14.04.

Openbravo is available on Launchpad, but is not supported after Precise Pangolin. I still tried to install it from this way, changing the `trusty` value from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openbravo-isv-ppa-trusty.list` to `hardy` after `apt-get update` yelled at me for a 404.

`apt-get update` now works, but `apt-get install openbravo-3` still tells me now that the dependencies `postgresql-9.1` is not installable, and `tomcat6-common` will simply not be installed.

I can still install `postgresql-9.1` normally, but `tomcat6` looks like it is not supported anymore on `trusty`, thus preventing me from installing it normally, even from the tarball. Maybe i am doing something wrong after all.

tl;dr : How can I install Openbravo3 on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I tried to install it on a VM in a move of despair.

The problem came from the `eclipse` package which requires `libtomcat7-java` and pretty much everything related to `tomcat7`. By removing `libtomcat7-java`, I went able to install `tomcat6`, but I had to remove ̀ eclipse`.

As you may have guessed, the same problem can go on any distro, not just Ubuntu Trusty.

I guess I will have to install a previous version of `eclipse` to properly work with it, or simply download and install the archive from their site.